# Linear layout inside relative layout is not seen in horizontal view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have 4 linear layout inside the relative layout and a button. I am able to see only first 3 relative layout and button in horizontal view. The fourth linearlayout is not seen but it is seen in the vertical view. Please help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gen"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gen"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text=" Search"
        android:textSize="25sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
     android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:src="@drawable/year"/>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/movieyear"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:text=" Search By Year"
         android:textSize="25sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/im"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imdb_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text=" Search"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/rt2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rotten_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text=" Search By Rating"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

 </LinearLayout>
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:id="@+id/filterbutton"
    android:text="filter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffff9a88"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep entire child linear layout inside scrollview so that it will be scrollable & visible.Check below updated xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/filterbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/gen" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/year" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movieyear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search By Year"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/im" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imdb_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/rt2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rotten_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search By Rating"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filterbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffff9a88"
        android:text="filter"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ScrollingView` as the parent,and inside that the `RelativeLayuot` and it add an scrollbar to see all.
You can see more info in android developers [ScrollingView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ScrollingView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWhole"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/cal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/cal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movieyear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search By Year"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/cal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imdb_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/cal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rotten_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" Search By Rating"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filterbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffff9a88"
        android:text="filter"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```